# How well does Nikon CLS commander mode work outdoors?

Tags: nikon, hotshoe-flash

I'm currently looking into CLS as an effective way of using off camera TTL and have been impresses so far.

I am wondering how well it will it work outside in bright conditions or at a long range and what about if the flash was behind me, and also behind a softbox maybe?

I have used radio triggers previously but the ones I have don't support TTL, could CLS be an effective way of using TLL off camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any optical based system will suffer issues in the conditions you have mentioned.  They will likely fail altogether in bright light and will need either line of sight, or something to reflect the light to the flash.

They can work reasonably well without direct line of sight indoors, where the walls will typically reflect the light, but outdoors, they are not going to work behind you, or if the receiver is blocked.

You will want radio triggers with support for TTL for these case.  You can get reasonably cheap ones like the [Yongnou 622N](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Yongnuo-YN-622N-Wireless-I-TTL-ITTL-HSS-1-8000S-Flash-Trigger-for-Nikon-/261660634761?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cec306e89) that work well (I have been happy with the Canon version).  These support TTL, groups and HSS.